# What kind of expansion is this?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

In a paper I came across an expansion like this:
$$\cos(m\theta) = C_m^0\cos^m(\theta) - C_m^2\cos^{m-2}(\theta)(1-\cos^2(\theta)) + C_m^4\cos^{m-4}(\theta)(1-\cos^2(\theta))^2 + ... 
 (-1)^nC_m^{2n}\cos^{m-2n}(\theta)(1-\cos^2(\theta))^n + ...$$

What kind of expansion is this and how do you calculate those $C_m^i$'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coefficients are binomial coefficients
$$C^k_m=\frac{m!}{k!\,(m-k)!}\ ,$$
though you should **note** that the notation used is slightly unusual, many people (AFAIK most people) write
$$C^m_k\quad\hbox{or}\quad {}^mC_k\quad\hbox{or}\quad \binom mk\ .$$
The formula comes from de Moivre's Theorem and the binomial expansion,
$$\eqalign{\cos(m\theta)
  &=\Re(\cos m\theta+i\sin m\theta)\cr
  &=\Re((\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^m)\cr
  &=\Re\biggl(\cos^m\theta+\binom m1\cos^{m-1}\theta(i\sin\theta)
    +\binom m2\cos^{m-2}\theta(i\sin\theta)^2+\cdots\biggr)\cr
  &=\cos^m\theta-\binom m2\cos^{m-2}\theta\sin^2\theta+\cdots\cr
  &=\cos^m\theta-\binom m2\cos^{m-2}\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)+\cdots\ .\cr}$$

Comment: You have explained very nice +1.

Comment: @David Thank you for the very nice explanation. Could you also tell me why somone might use this expansion? Are there any other expansions? What is the advantage of this expansion? Sorry I'm a math newbie :D

Comment: Mainly because it shows that if you know the value of $\cos\theta$ (and in some cases you will need $\sin\theta$ too) you can find $\cos2\theta$, $\cos3\theta$ etc.

Comment: @David That makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)
$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^m=\cos m\theta+i\sin m\theta$$
write the expansion of the left side and then pick up the real part of both sides. You will find the desired formula.

Comment: You are welcome.